# How can I solve a fifth degree polynomial in C++

Tags: c++, polynomial-math

I have a quintic function (5th degree polynomial) and I would like to solve it in C++. 
Is there an implementation or a math library I can use in order to proceed?

Comment: perhaps this is of interest? 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/roots2.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on the numerical method comment?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html

Comment: I don't get the reason for down voting or the close inquiry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your problem: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/General-Polynomial-Equations.html

Answer (score 4):

Boost has this. Have a look here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/roots2.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals2/polynomials.html

> Description
>
> These functions solve the root of some function f(x) without the need
>   for the derivatives of f(x). The functions here that use TOMS
>   Algorithm 748 are asymptotically the most efficient known, and have
>   been shown to be optimal for a certain classes of smooth functions.
>
> Alternatively, there is a simple bisection routine which can be useful
>   in its own right in some situations, or alternatively for narrowing
>   down the range containing the root, prior to calling a more advanced
>   algorithm.

Unfortunately these libraries are not beginner friendly, and I could not yet find an example on how to use them. Answer delivered *as-is* for now. For now, have a look here
http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/Boost/Math/Tools/TOMS748

You should be able to plug in a boost polynomial instead of t.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a quintic function (5th degree polyonimial) and I would like to solve it in C++.

There's a problem here, a rather famous one. There's a simple solution to quadratic equations. Cubic equations are a bit tougher. One way to solve them analytically is via Cardano's method. Quartic equations are tougher yet, but still can be solved analytically.

And that's where it ends. *There is no formula for the roots of a fifth degree polynomial equation (or higher) that can be written in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial and only uses the standard algebraic operations.* An entire branch of mathematics, Galois theory, resulted from one of the proofs that a general purpose analytic solution for quintics does not exist.

What that means is that you will have to resort to numerical root finding techniques.